# "Wrong number of indices inside []": Why?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I'm getting compilation error "Wrong number of indices insice [] : expected 1". But why? I think I'm not doing anything strange.

Here is the code (inside one function):

```
// **valoresMonedas is a Int32[] array passed as parameter**
Int32[] valores = valoresMonedas; 
Int32[][] matrixnN;

Int32 valMon = valoresMonedas.Count();
matrixnN = new Int32[valMon][]; 

for (Int32 i=0;i< cantidadTotal;i++){
  // **cantidadTotal is a Int32 passed as parameter**
  matrixnN[i] = new Int32[cantidadTotal]; 
}

for (Int32 i=0;i< valMon; i++){
  matrixnN[i][0] = 0;
}

// some code... (just if / for / assignations ..)
matrixnN[0][1] = 1 + matrixnN[1, 1 + valores[1]]; // <-- THE ERROR IS HERE
```

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: Looks like C# to me, not C. Please correct your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `matrixnN[1, 1 + valores[1]]` should be `matrixnN[1][1 + valores[1]]`

Answer (score 2):

You have to do

```
matrixnN[1][1 + valores[1]]
```

or some other combination of two indexes, not

```
matrixnN[1, 1 + valores[1]]
```

you have an erroneous comma where there should be another pair of brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean?

```
matrixnN[0][1] = 1 + matrixnN[1][1 + valores[1]];
```